# Symfony 3 routing with slug. Route with last slash without slug shows 404 page

Tags: symfony, symfony-routing

I've started using Symfony. I was trying to set up routing with slugs and had a problem.

When I enter no slug and no last slash *site.me/lucky/number* it's ok.
But when I enter no slug with lash slash *site.me/lucky/number/* I get 404 page.
I found a workaround for it with additional "root" route, it can be seen in my routing file below.

Is it possible to use a single route entry?
Is it possible to use multiple routes for the same action? Something like creating a link to a single route entry configured, so I don't have to make similar changes in many route entries.

I use php built-in server on ubuntu 16.

```
<!-- routing.xml -->
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<routes xmlns="http://symfony.com/schema/routing"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://symfony.com/schema/routing
    http://symfony.com/schema/routing/routing-1.0.xsd">
    <route id="homepage" path="/">
        <default key="_controller">AppBundle:Default:index</default>
    </route>
    <route id="lucky_number_root" path="lucky/number/">
        <default key="_controller">AppBundle:Lucky:number</default>
        <default key="max">100</default>
    </route>
    <route id="lucky_number" path="lucky/number/{max}">
        <default key="_controller">AppBundle:Lucky:number</default>
        <default key="max">100</default>
        <requirement key="max">\d+</requirement>
    </route>
</routes>
```

Comment: http://symfony.com/doc/current/routing/redirect_trailing_slash.html

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried changing your routing.xml file to something like this:

```
<route id="lucky_number" path="/lucky/number/{max}/">
  <default key="_controller">AppBundle:Lucky:number</default>
  <default key="max">100</default>
  <requirement key="max">\d+</requirement>
</route>
```

I think that might work - try it. Just added the backslash at the end.

**EDIT #2**
NOTE: It was missing a backslash in front - try that

Comment: I tried this. Neither site.me/lucky/number nor site.me/lucky/number/ works. Only site.me/lucky/number/4/ works. Also I tried disabling requirement and it didn't help. Thanks for reply.

Comment: But it helped with site.me/lucky/number/4 - redirects to site.me/lucky/number/4/

Comment: for EDIT #2 didn't help

Answer (score 0):

make `max` parameter optional `<requirement key="max">\d*</requirement>`

```
<!-- routing.xml -->
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<routes xmlns="http://symfony.com/schema/routing"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://symfony.com/schema/routing
    http://symfony.com/schema/routing/routing-1.0.xsd">
    <route id="homepage" path="/">
        <default key="_controller">AppBundle:Default:index</default>
    </route>
    <route id="lucky_number_root" path="lucky/number/">
        <default key="_controller">AppBundle:Lucky:number</default>
        <default key="max">100</default>
    </route>
    <route id="lucky_number" path="lucky/number/{max}">
        <default key="_controller">AppBundle:Lucky:number</default>
        <default key="max">100</default>
        <requirement key="max">\d*</requirement>
    </route>
</routes>
```

also you can remove `lucky_number_root` route in this case

Comment: I tried some ugly workaround which helped with my 1st question using your idea. I moved default to controller and made route look this 
    <route id="lucky_number" path="/lucky/number{slash}{max}{slash1}">
        <default key="_controller">AppBundle:Lucky:number</default>
        <default key="max">100</default>
        <requirement key="max">\d*</requirement>
        <requirement key="slash">\/?</requirement>
        <requirement key="slash1">\/?</requirement>
    </route>

Comment: So having multiple routes with same content is less evil to me